# Loading xml into flash movie hosted on IIS6 server, not working

Tags: xml, flash, iis, iis-6

I have a flash file that loads an XML file at runtime. When the `.swf` file is run locally or on an Apache server it works fine but when hosted on an IIS6 based server the file won't load.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Can you tell if your flash movie gets an error when trying to fetch the file, and if so, which error is it?

Comment: i can't tell if its generating an error, i don't have access to the source files

Comment: it would also help to know if you can pull up the XML via the URL you're feeding to the SWF file. If you get an error trying to do that it may better suggest what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You may have file permission issues. Make sure that your xml file has read permissions for the "Network service" account (or ASPNET user if you are on XP)

If you are trying to load an FLV you will also need to set that up as a mime type in IIS. This is usually not set up by default.

Comment: this didn't work, I explicitly added the Network Service to the entire directory and no change. there are no flv files either

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue... everything loads fine locally, even referencing the web server locations from my local machine in Flash... when uploading the swf and the same paths, the xml image paths are not loaded in...

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading the XML from a domain other than that where the SWF is hosted you will run into the "cross domain security" issue.  Some docs here:

http://kb.adobe.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalId=tn_14213&sliceId=2